# use closure inside underscorejs template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Just wondering if there is any value in using a closure in an underscore template...say to keep track of counters or something.  Here's a trivial example of what I mean:

```
<% 
 (function( models ){
  var length = models.length-1,
      section = "";
    _.each( models, function ( item, index ) {
        if (index === 0) {
          section = "top";
        } else if (index === length) {
          section = "bottom";
        } else {
          section = "center";
        }
    %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gradiantDiv <%= section %>content">
      <a href="/#customer/<%= item._id %>">
        <address>
          <strong><%= item.name %></strong><br>
          <%= item.addr1 %><br>
          <%= item.city %>, <%= item.state %> <%= item.zip %><br>
          <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> <%= item.phone %>
        </address>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="gradiantDiv <%= section %>action">
        <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
<% 
    });
})( models );
%>
```

Or is it just better to declare variables like "length" and "section" without a closure before the _.each? OR does it matter at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally know of any advantage to creating variables that wouldn't otherwise make sense outside of a template.

We normally create variables when they optimize or make code more readable.

(e.g.

**length** is only used once. I think its more readable and less work to use it in place. I've been rightly scolded during peer checkin reviews for creating variables just for the sake of some perceived legibility.

**section** is used many times and requires additional logic so it makes a lot of sense.

**models** doesn't do anything except force the interpreter to create a new pointer, why pass it in when it's available in a containing scope?

)

If it makes code more legible, or optimizes something then I'd say it's worth it.